# How can I optimize a operation with the Database in django?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a query which looks something like this:

```
SELECT
     STRAIGHT_JOIN  `reviewApp_review`.`id`, `reviewApp_review`.`reviewTitle`,
        `reviewApp_review`.`reviewContent`, `reviewApp_review`.`translatedEnTitle`,
        `reviewApp_review`.`translatedEnContent`, `reviewApp_review`.`translatedEnDate`,
        `reviewApp_review`.`reviewLink`, `reviewApp_review`.`reviewUser`,
        `reviewApp_review`.`reviewUserProfile`, `reviewApp_review`.`reviewDataCreated`,
        `reviewApp_review`.`reviewDataDiscovered`, `reviewApp_review`.`reviewData`,
        `reviewApp_review`.`reviewRating`, `reviewApp_review`.`reviewSignature`,
        `reviewApp_review`.`reviewSignature2`, `reviewApp_review`.`reviewExternalId`,
        `reviewApp_review`.`reviewStatus`, `reviewApp_review`.`reviewWebsite`,
        `reviewApp_review`.`language`, `reviewApp_review`.`helpfulVotes`,
        `reviewApp_review`.`verified`, `reviewApp_review`.`color`,
        `reviewApp_review`.`style`, `reviewApp_review`.`size`,
        `reviewApp_review`.`lastUpdated`, `reviewApp_review`.`lastSeen`,
        `reviewApp_review`.`deleted`, `reviewApp_review`.`alerted`,
        `reviewApp_review`.`analyzed`, `reviewApp_review`.`productLink_id`
    FROM  `reviewApp_review`
    INNER JOIN  `reviewApp_productlink`  ON (`reviewApp_review`.`productLink_id` = `reviewApp_productlink`.`id`)
    INNER JOIN  `reviewApp_product`  ON (`reviewApp_productlink`.`product_id` = `reviewApp_product`.`id`)
    WHERE  (`reviewApp_product`.`owner` = 'my product'
              AND  `reviewApp_productlink`.`customer_id` = '1241'
              AND  (`reviewApp_review`.`translatedEnContent` LIKE '%%urban%%'
                      OR  (`reviewApp_review`.`reviewContent` LIKE '%%urban%%'
                              AND  `reviewApp_review`.`translatedEnDate` = '0'))
           )
    ORDER BY  `reviewApp_review`.`reviewRating` ASC
    LIMIT  10
```

I want to select reviews from the database and when a result is a number of reviews under 10, it takes a lot of time, more than a minute. And I'm wondering if there is a solution to optimize this query.

I tried to make different operations in the SQL query, as you can see I tried to use STRAIGHT_JOIN, and INNER_JOIN but I didn't have a better time.

The result of the query should be a querySet that contains a list of reviews, matching all those conditions from the query.
From Django I'm using something like that to run this query:

```
querySet.model.objects.raw(rawQuery)
```

where rawQuery is the query described above.

Here I have a python function and I want to optimize it because it takes to much time.

```
def fixQS(querySet):
    """
    Optimisation for SQL QUERY using order by
    https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40195/246455
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#extra
    STRAIGHT_JOIN
    """

    # complete the SQL with params encapsulated in quotes
    sql, params = querySet.query.sql_with_params()
    newParams = ()
    for param in params:
        if not str(param).startswith("'"):
            if isinstance(param, str):
                param = re.sub("'", "\\'", param)
            newParams = newParams + ("'{}'".format(param),)
        else:
            newParams = newParams + (param,)
    rawQuery = sql % newParams

    # escape the percent used in SQL LIKE statements
    rawQuery = re.sub('%', '%%', rawQuery)

    # replace SELECT with SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
    rawQuery = rawQuery.replace('SELECT', 'SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN')

    return querySet.model.objects.raw(rawQuery)
```

I'm calling it like this :

```
currentReviews = fixQS(currentReviews)
```

And when the debugger evaluates this it takes a lot of time.

Here is the result of the command SHOW CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `reviewApp_review` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reviewTitle` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reviewContent` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reviewLink` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reviewDataCreated` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reviewDataDiscovered` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reviewRating` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reviewSignature` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reviewStatus` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `productLink_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reviewWebsite` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `style` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `alerted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `reviewUser` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reviewUserProfile` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reviewSignature2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reviewData` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reviewExternalId` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `helpfulVotes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastSeen` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastUpdated` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `translatedEnContent` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `translatedEnDate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `translatedEnTitle` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `analyzed` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `reviewApp_re_productLink_id_084fa2ec_fk_reviewApp_productlink_id` (`productLink_id`),
  KEY `reviewApp_review_reviewSignature_2c31b21d_uniq` (`reviewSignature`),
  KEY `reviewApp_review_reviewSignature_224ab822_idx` (`reviewSignature`,`productLink_id`),
  KEY `reviewApp_review_fa0816ae` (`reviewSignature2`),
  KEY `reviewApp_review_alerted_57344ef1_uniq` (`alerted`),
  KEY `reviewApp_review_reviewData_5dd52e46_uniq` (`reviewData`),
  KEY `reviewApp_review_reviewRating_d418fcfc_uniq` (`reviewRating`),
  KEY `reviewApp_review_reviewWebsite_25d7fd04_uniq` (`reviewWebsite`),
  KEY `reviewApp_review_reviewExternalId_32dfb169_uniq` (`reviewExternalId`),
  KEY `reviewApp_reviewContent` (`reviewContent`(100)),
  KEY `reviewApp_translatedEnContent` (`translatedEnContent`(100)),
  KEY `reviewApp_translatedEnDate` (`translatedEnDate`),
  KEY `reviewApp_review_da602f0b` (`deleted`),
  KEY `reviewApp_review_language_3de815cd_uniq` (`language`),
  KEY `reviewApp_review_order_index` (`reviewData`),
  KEY `reviewApp_review_rating_order_index` (`reviewRating`),
  KEY `reviewApp_review_rating_order_index_desc` (`reviewRating`),
  CONSTRAINT `reviewApp_re_productLink_id_084fa2ec_fk_reviewApp_productlink_id` FOREIGN KEY (`productLink_id`) REFERENCES `reviewApp_productlink` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24274768 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

And this one is for the product:

```
CREATE TABLE `reviewApp_product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `owner` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ean` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `internalCode` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `asin` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `reviewApp_product_name_37c04b41_uniq` (`name`,`customer_id`),
  KEY `reviewApp_product_cb24373b` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `reviewApp_product_name_23da262c_uniq` (`name`),
  KEY `reviewApp_product_owner_680ac2b4_uniq` (`owner`),
  KEY `reviewApp_product_index` (`owner`,`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `reviewApp_product_customer_id_7663d434_fk_reviewApp_customer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `reviewApp_customer` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31556 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

And also for productLink I have this:

```
CREATE TABLE `reviewApp_productlink` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productLink` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productDataCreated` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `domain` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `httpStatus` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `externalProductId` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ratingsNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `fb_data` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `reviewApp_productl_customer_id_f0141212_fk_reviewApp_customer_id` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `reviewApp_productlink_9bea82de` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `reviewApp_productl_customer_id_f0141212_fk_reviewApp_customer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `reviewApp_customer` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `reviewApp_productlin_product_id_6123214e_fk_reviewApp_product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `reviewApp_product` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=127823 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with django or python as you are executing a raw sql query. In order for us to help, you must add: 1) the results of the explain of your query 2) the create table statement of each underlying table with all indexes and their fields included.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `STRAIGHT_JOIN` so that the Optimizer is allowed to try looking at the tables in different orders.  The following composite indexes may give the Optimizer *better* options:

```
reviewApp_review:  INDEX(translatedEnContent, reviewContent,
                      translatedEnDate, productLink_id, reviewRating)
reviewApp_productlink:  INDEX(customer_id,  product_id, id)
reviewApp_product:  INDEX(owner, id)
```

`translatedEnDate` is a DATE?  Yet you are testing for "0"??

**More**

(repeating original, but with aliases to shorten the text)

```
SELECT
     STRAIGHT_JOIN  rr.((lots of stuff))
    FROM  `reviewApp_review` AS rr
    INNER JOIN  `reviewApp_productlink` AS pl  ON (rr.`productLink_id` = pl.`id`)
    INNER JOIN  `reviewApp_product` AS p  ON (pl.`product_id` = p.`id`)
    WHERE  (  p.`owner` = 'my product'
      AND    pl.`customer_id` = '1241'
      AND    (rr.`translatedEnContent` LIKE '%%urban%%'
                  OR  (   rr.`reviewContent` LIKE '%%urban%%'
                     AND  rr.`translatedEnDate` = '0')
           ) )
    ORDER BY  rr.`reviewRating` ASC
    LIMIT  10
```

You seem to be gathering all those columns only to throw away all but 10 rows.  An optimization is to first find the 10 ids, *then* fetch the rest of the columns:

```
SELECT  rr.((lots of stuff))
    FROM  ( SELECT rr2.id
              FROM reviewApp_review` AS rr2
              INNER JOIN  `reviewApp_productlink` AS pl
                    ON (rr2.`productLink_id` = pl.`id`)
              INNER JOIN  `reviewApp_product` AS p
                    ON (pl.`product_id` = p.`id`)
              WHERE (  p.`owner` = 'my product'
                AND   pl.`customer_id` = '1241'
                AND   ( rr2.`translatedEnContent` LIKE '%%urban%%'
                         OR  (    rr2.`reviewContent` LIKE '%%urban%%'
                             AND  rr2.`translatedEnDate` = '0')
                    ) )
              ORDER BY  rr2.`reviewRating` ASC
              LIMIT  10
          ) AS ids
    INNER JOIN reviewApp_review` AS rr  ON ids.id = rr.id
    ORDER BY  rr.`reviewRating` ASC   -- Yes, this needs repeating

p: INDEX(owner)
pl:  INDEX(customer_id, product_id)
reviewApp_review:  INDEX(productLink_id, reviewRating)
reviewApp_review:  INDEX(reviewRating)
```

These are useless (at least for the current query):

```
KEY `reviewApp_reviewContent` (`reviewContent`(100)),
KEY `reviewApp_translatedEnContent` (`translatedEnContent`(100)),
```

Better *might* be

```
FULLTEXT(translatedEnContent),
FULLTEXT(reviewContent)
```

together with

```
MATCH(reviewContent) AGAINST ('+urban' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
MATCH(translatedEnContent) AGAINST ('+urban' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But, unfortunately, it won't be cheap to do the subquery.  The hope is that 'my product' and '1241' do enough filtering to minimize the usage of `LIKE` or `MATCH`.

A minor side note:  When you have `INDEX(a,b)` or `UNIQUE(a,b)`, it is unnecessary to also have `INDEX(a)`.  (I see several instances of this.)

Even better...

If possible, get rid of the test on `translatedEnDate` and combine the two text columns:

```
FULLTEXT(reviewContent, translatedEnContent)
MATCH(reviewContent, translatedEnContent) 
       AGAINST ('+urban' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This will make it possible to start the search with an efficient FT lookup, followed by checking the `owner` and `customer_id`.  This would avoid a full table scan of the multi-GB `reviewApp_review`.

Comment: TranslatedEnDate is an integer.
Can you tell me how can I use those Indexes?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE review... ADD INDEX(...);`  -- is that what you are asking?  This action _may_ take a long time (depending on version of MySQL and size of table).  (INT = 0 -- OK.)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to optimize the query and you told me that I can do that with indexes. But I don't want it to take a long time to execute.

Comment: Improving the indexes will allow this query to take less time each time you run the query.

Comment: I observed that if I remove straight_join the query works very slowly for those where it has to return thousands of records and for queries with under one thousand works fine and fast. DO you know a best practice or something like that for this problem?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables involved.  There could be a datatype or collation discrepancy that is causing trouble.

Comment: I edited my question with the output of this command.

Comment: @OnlyAUser - Thanks.  I added to my Answer.